Convert .lyr to QGIS project not working due to database connection
I am currently trying to import layer data from ArcMap into QGIS via SLYR. This also works with normal layers, but not with those that refer to data in an Oracle SDE database.
When I want to convert the layers to QGIS, I am always prompted to log in to the database (user name + password). Unfortunately, this does not work with the settings for the database.
I always thought that the connection to the database is already part of the .lyr file, so why doesn't it work in QGIS? Especially as I can also connect to the database in QGIS as normal.
Yes, I know that it is possible to convert .mxd files with the paid license of SLYR, but I wanted to test the inexpensive version first.

I just found out that I can also add the layer if I cancel and close the connection popup. Then I can open a window called "Repair data source" and select the original data source in my previously connected database. However, with a dataset of over 30 layers, this is not the way to go.

QGIS cannot read an encrypted password  from a layer file.

Allright, so there is no solution for the problem? Will it work when i load the .mxd-file with SLYR?

No solution. Same issue.

I believe QGIS cannot directly utilize ArcGIS's enterprise-level geodatabase. The reason is straightforward: ArcGIS does not support Open Database Connectivity (ODBC), and its database engine differs significantly from PostGIS. Additionally, ArcGIS performs software licensing validation. The best approach would be to store the data in a Geodatabase (GDB) and then import it into PostgreSQL (PG).
